# Is Ehcache force reload possible?

Tags: ehcache

I have two separate web applications to handle a website for customers and other admin application for call center agents. Using the build script I am bundling the same model classes into both web applications.
There is a database for customers where we keep the password. If we change the password from website it should be immediately shown in the admin site. I am not using distributed cache.

Is there a simple way that I can enforce reload from database for a specific flow? So that I can reload from database if I want to get the password property.

Answer (score 0):

If you don`t want using distributed cache, you could remove element from admin cache. Customers application should notify admin application about this event. Possible way to notify is simple rest call.